# How to get each element of a array from user input then pass it to a function in another file in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, scanf, element

How can I get each element of an array from user input then pass it to a function in another file. I'm having trouble and need help please. This my code.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lab8.h"

int x[100];
int y[100];

int main(void) {  
    int count, i, product;

    printf("Enter the length of both arrays\n");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    printf("Enter the first array's elements\n");
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        scanf("%i", &x[i]);
    }
    printf("Element: %i\n", x[i]);
    printf("Enter the second array's elements\n");
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        scanf("%i", &y[i]);
    }   
    product = inner_product(x, y, count);
    printf("Inner product: %i\n", product);

    return(0);
}
```

**lab8.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lab8.h"

int inner_product(int a[], int b[], int count) {
    int i;
    int result = 0;

    for( i=1; i<count; i++) {
        result = result + (a[i] * b[i]);
    }    
    return result;
}
```

It only seems to multiply the last element entered for both arrays heres the output.

```
Enter the length of both arrays
2
Enter the first array's elements
1
2
Element: 0
Enter the second array's elements
3
3
Inner product: 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating from `1` and you should iterate from `0`, in the `inner_product()` function

```
for( i=1; i<count; i++) {
/*     ^ this should be 0 */
```

also, don't use global variables specially because you got the rest of it right, you are passing the arrays as arguments to the `inner_product()` function.

Comment: You know, since the function's name is `inner_product()` I assume that you are a physics student, as one you can be used to `maple` where arrays are indexed from `1` to `N` or probably `pascal` which I don't remember if it too indexes the arrays that way, in c it's from `0` to `N-1`, and I suppose that it's related to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Computer science major. And thanks for the help. So I shouldn't use the the global variables x and y?

Comment: No, that's a bad idea in general, only in very special situations global variables are ok. But in your case you don't even need them.

Comment: so just declare them as variables in main(); and I will be good?

Comment: @CodyHutto yes, just that.

Comment: @CodyHutto take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), you will earn a badge if you read it all.